# httpclient method get android not working

Tags: android, get, httpclient

I'm having some problems when I try to call a php function (method get) from an android app. The code in the app is:

```
 try {
        String link="http://localhost?name=" + name;
        System.out.println(link);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(link);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {                    
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        Log.v("My Response :: ", result);


  }catch(Exception e){
     Log.i("error", ("Exception: " + e.getMessage()));
  }
```

and in the server side the php code is:

```
  <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","emergency");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $name = $_GET['name'];


   $sql = "INSERT INTO data (name, age, cell, sex, status, ocupation, origin, residence, contactName, phone1, phone2, latitude, longitude) values ('".$name."',23,'22256602','true','soltero','empleado','mexicano','puebla','Marua','552786','','19.038306','-98.20621')";

   echo $sql . "</br></br></br>";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
   echo "1 record added";

   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

The problem is I've tryed different ways but still returns me a null exception.. What can I do? :s Thak you very much!!

Comment: Returns a null execption? Can you please post your stacktrace error?

Comment: `Log.i("error", ("Exception: " + e.getMessage()));` If you would allow a full stacktrace to be printed the debugging would be much easier!

Comment: The full stacktrace sends
      `Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not establish network connections from the UI thread. That is why you got the Exception:

```
 Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You should move your code that connects to your server into a background thread, for example with an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

One of the main reasons why this should be done asynchronously is to avoid a frozen UI.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is pointing to your local android device. If you want to connect your computer PC set it's IP address instead of `localhost` for example `http://192.168.1.1?name=`

Comment: I posted it as localhost because of security prevention, I do have an ip instead of localhost...

Comment: @Eduardo you should mention that in your question then. And better put some fake IP to make this clear. Also a complete stacktrace would really help.